# Difference between "develop" and "create"

Tags: word-usage, meaning

What is the difference between these two sentences:

- Scientists are **developing** new drugs to treat arthritis
- Scientists are **creating** new drugs to treat arthritis

Comment: You can **develop** something that has been already **created**.

Answer (score 3):

There's not much difference in this example.  "Developing" new drugs puts more emphasis on the amount of work required to create the drugs—they cannot simply be *created* with what they already have, but need to be *developed* through research and testing.

Given that and the fact that most drugs *do* require a hefty amount of research and development, I'd typically lean toward "developing," but either is perfectly fine.  A case where I'd strongly suggest "creating" is in a future where we are confident in a specific *process* for creating a new drug that can be quickly applied to new diseases—for instance, Moderna's COVID-19 vaccine, which was [apparently created in two days](https://theness.com/neurologicablog/index.php/it-took-two-days-to-develop-modernas-vaccine/).  Of course, it took a long time to test, but the actual *creation* was straightforward, given what they'd already *developed*.

Comment: Create refers to a new thing; but develop may not always be so. We can develop something to a better one, whereas we always create a new one.

Comment: I agree about the emphasis on the work involved - the process is generally called *research and development*, which involves learning about things and going through a (usually long, iterative) process to produce a new or better version of something. I wouldn't get hung up on the *newness* aspect because that's very subjective (is anything truly new and original? how much do you need to develop something before it becomes a separate, "new" thing?) but *create* feels like it glosses over the effort and time involved, *develop* puts more of an emphasis on it.

Answer (score 0):

Creating is the act of bringing something into existence that did not exist before, while developing is the act of growing something into a more mature / advanced state.

So you would create the drug and then develop it.

Hence in terms of your sentences. When you talk about “creating” a new drug, it would imply there is no drug in currently in existence. Whilst when you talk about “developing” a drug, it would imply that there is already one, but you are improving it.

In normal conversation most people will not dwell on the subtle difference.